# How can I add an updatable input field that shows the 'user_pass' encrypted data in the Edit Profile section?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the encrypted `user_pass` data from my `wp_users` table in my database to show up as a custom editable and updatable field (like the email field) in the "Edit User" pages within the admin side only. I have come up with the following code:

```
if ( is_admin() ) { 
    add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' ); 
    add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' ); 
    function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
<h3>Additional Account Information</h3>
<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:20.5%!important;">Existing Password (Encrypted)</th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" value="<?php  echo esc_attr($user->user_pass) ?>" class="regular-text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
    $user_id = wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'user_pass'  => $_POST[ 'user_pass' ] ) );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The code above is working but when it updates it is re-encrypting the already encrypted password I am copy and pasting. Thereby making the encrypted password the password itself! I just want it to save the exact way I paste it in. Is this even possible?

I want this data so I am able to copy and paste it from one user area to another within my site as they do not share databases, however some users need to be in more than one database with the same information including password. I would like to be able to do that right from the Wordpress Admin areas instead of in phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying replacing this :

```
<input type="text" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" value="<?php  echo esc_attr( get_userdata( $user->user_pass, $user->ID ) );; ?>" class="regular-text" />
```

by this :

```
<input type="text" name="user_pass" id="user_pass" value="<?= esc_attr($user->user_pass) ?>" class="regular-text" />
```

**EDIT :**

Here's the code to update the password field in DB :

```
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'update_extra_user_fields' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'update_extra_user_fields' );

function update_extra_user_fields($user_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id)) return;

    $user = get_user_by('ID', $user_id);

    if (isset($_POST['user_pass']) && !empty($_POST['user_pass'])) {
        if ($user->user_pass != $_POST['user_pass']) {
            $wpdb->update(
                $wpdb->users,
                array(
                    'user_pass'           => $_POST['user_pass'],
                ),
                array( 'ID' => $user_id )
            );

            wp_cache_delete( $user_id, 'users' );
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for the delay!

Comment: This does display the encrypted password thanks! But it does not update after I change it. It goes back to the original one that was there...

Comment: I edited my answer to include the update part. Tell me if that makes it for you.

Comment: I added an update to my code above. I'm trying to get yours to work but I'm getting a php error and it crashes my site until I delete your posted function. Just FYI I'm posting all this in my functions.php file. The issue now is that it is re-hashing the already hashed password I'm trying to save it as.

Comment: Did you remove your previous "save_extra_user_profile_fields" function ?

Comment: yes I did. Then copy and pasted exactly what you have above

Comment: Can you set **WP_DEBUG** to **TRUE** in wp-config.php and tell me what the error message is? The above code was tested on WP 5.2.2 (PHP 7.2.11). What is your WP version ? PHP version ? Thanks.

Comment: This was an error on my end. I was deleting the closing curly brace that was closing the `if ( is_admin() ) { ` The code works. Thank you!